# Filtering out the values of inner dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have dictionary,

```
dict={
     {'dept': 'ECE', 'id': 1, 'name': 'asif', 'City': 'Bangalore'},
     {'dept': 'ECE', 'id': 2, 'name': 'iqbal', 'City': 'Kolkata'}
}
```

I wanted to is there any way so that I can filter out the name and dept on the basis of City?

I tried but couldn't find any way out.

Comment: That's not a dict, that's a set of dicts. This probably does not even work since dictionaries are unhashable.

Comment: That does not work in python. Just tried to cut paste. If you make it an array of dictionaries I can help you.

Comment: yeah.. please help me in this case.

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: @alvarez...

Hi alvarez i was trying that if we can filter the value from the array of dictionary when the the id == 1 something like that.
But on further trying i came to its not possible as dictionaries are not hashable.
but we can separate each dictionary and covert them into list

Answer (score 1):

Ok, If I understand your question, and  from the fact that set has been converted to a list, I think something like that could be what you are looking for:

```
data=[
     {'dept': 'ECE', 'id': 1, 'name': 'asif', 'City': 'Bangalore'},
     {'dept': 'ECE', 'id': 2, 'name': 'iqbal', 'City': 'Kolkata'},
]

my_keys = ('name','dept',)
my_cities = ['Kolkata',]

my_dicts = [{key:value for key, value in dictionary.items() if key in my_keys} for dictionary in data if dictionary['City'] in my_cities]
print(my_dicts)
```